# Index errors on start up on Azure environment

Tags: azure, azure-search

When starting our application we are seeing lots of these entries:

```
2017-06-29T08:38:59  PID[60944] Error       8168 08:38:59 ERROR Custodian.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick. Update index last updated failed
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException
Message: Index sitecore_web_index was not found
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.EventHub.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick(Object state)


2017-06-29T08:39:00  PID[60944] Error       57480 08:39:00 ERROR Custodian.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick. Update index last updated failed
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException
Message: Index sitecore_web_index was not found
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.EventHub.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick(Object state)


2017-06-29T08:39:01  PID[60944] Error       57480 08:39:01 ERROR Custodian.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick. Update index last updated failed
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException
Message: Index sitecore_web_index was not found
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.EventHub.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick(Object state)


2017-06-29T08:39:02  PID[60944] Error       28556 08:39:02 ERROR Custodian.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick. Update index last updated failed
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException
Message: Index sitecore_web_index was not found
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.EventHub.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick(Object state)


2017-06-29T08:39:03  PID[60944] Error       8168 08:39:03 ERROR Custodian.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick. Update index last updated failed
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException
Message: Index sitecore_web_index was not found
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.EventHub.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick(Object state)


2017-06-29T08:39:04  PID[60944] Error       8168 08:39:04 ERROR Custodian.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick. Update index last updated failed
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException
Message: Index sitecore_web_index was not found
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.EventHub.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick(Object state)


2017-06-29T08:39:05  PID[60944] Error       8168 08:39:05 ERROR Custodian.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick. Update index last updated failed
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException
Message: Index sitecore_web_index was not found
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.EventHub.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick(Object state)


2017-06-29T08:39:06  PID[60944] Error       44084 08:39:06 ERROR Custodian.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick. Update index last updated failed
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException
Message: Index sitecore_web_index was not found
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.EventHub.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick(Object state)


2017-06-29T08:39:07  PID[60944] Error       28556 08:39:07 ERROR Custodian.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick. Update index last updated failed
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException
Message: Index sitecore_web_index was not found
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.EventHub.UpdateIndexTimestampTimerTick(Object state)
```

I have found the [following fix](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/398869) for what appears to be for a similar issue, but in that case, it was for distributed environments. In this case, we are running the CD & CM together.

Eventually, the instance starts, but it takes a good few minutes and the logs are littered with these entries which suggest there is something wrong?

We are running `Sitecore 8.2 rev. 161221`

Comment: We have the same on CM, so we disabled the sitecore_web_index (this is not a solution, this is just to be able to access the site) and the same on CD with sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web (no solution found !)